# how to examine a relationship between categorical variables with several levels?

Tags: regression, ordinal-data, ordered-logit, cross-section

I would like examine if the job satisfaction of part-time workers is higher or lower compared to full-time workers.

My dataset consists of 4125 cross-sectional observations.

independent variable: employment status (1 = full-time, 2 = part-time)

dependent variable: job satisfaction (0 = Very dissatisfied, 25 = Dissatisfied, 50 = Neutral, 75 = Satisfied 100 = Very satisfied)

What kind of statistical test do I need?

How could I incorporate (categorical) control variables (e.g. age, gender, tenure, etc.)?

Comment: Look into ordinal regression, search this site.

Comment: I seem to remember you asking this question a few days ago.  I recommended ordinal regression in order to perform the appropriate tests while controlling for covariates.  The `rms` package in R has some facilities for this regression.  I suggest you start there.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to examine the relationship between categorical variables with several levels?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/464249/how-to-examine-the-relationship-between-categorical-variables-with-several-level)