# How to examine the relationship between categorical variables with several levels?

Tags: regression, categorical-data, ordinal-data

I would like examine if the job satisfaction of part-time workers is higher or lower compared to full-time workers.

My dataset consists of 4125 cross-sectional observations.

independent variable: employment status (1 = full-time, 2 = part-time)

dependent variable: job satisfaction (0 = Very dissatisfied, 25 = Dissatisfied, 50 = Neutral, 75 = Satisfied 100 = Very satisfied)

What kind of statistical test do I need for my analysis?

How could I incorporate (categorical) control variables (e.g. age, gender, tenure, etc.)?

Answer (score 1):

**Viewing satisfactions scores as levels of a categorical variable.** There are various possible approaches. One of the simplest is to
put the counts into a $2 \times 5$ table and do a chi-squared test
for independence. Your satisfaction scores are essentially a Likert
scale with percentages proportional to numbers 1 through 5, used in
the fake example below:

```
Satis    1    2    3    4    5   TOTAL
Full   191  319  329  456  675    1970
Part   562  603  419  267  275    2126
```

Analysis in R:

```
f = c(191, 319, 329, 456, 675)
p = c(562, 603, 419, 267, 275)
TBL = rbind(f, p)
chisq.test(TBL)

        Pearson's Chi-squared test

data:  TBL
X-squared = 493.7, df = 4, p-value < 2.2e-16
```

With P-value so near zero, there is strong evidence of association
between Full/Part time and Satisfaction.

Expected counts $E_{ij}$ for the ten cells of the table are computed from row and column totals of the table of counts---assuming that the null hypothesis of no association between the two categorical variables to be true. You can see the expected counts as follows:

```
cq.out = chisq.test(TBL)
cq.out$exp
      [,1]     [,2]     [,3]     [,4]     [,5]
f 362.1606 443.4424 359.7559 347.7319 456.9092
p 390.8394 478.5576 388.2441 375.2681 493.0908
```

Observed counts #X_{ij}$ are the corresponding (integer) counts in `TBL`.
Comparing observed and expected counts, you can see that part time
workers tend to have more than the expected number of counts in
the lower-numbered satisfaction categories.

The Pearson residuals
are the 'signed' square roots of the ten quantities 
$\frac{(X_{ij} - E_{IJ})^2}{E_{ij}}$ can be displayed as follows:

```
cq.out$res
       [,1]      [,2]      [,3]      [,4]      [,5]
f -8.994008 -5.909486 -1.621526  5.806014 10.202872
p  8.657745  5.688545  1.560901 -5.588942 -9.821412
```

Usually, Pearson residuals with absolute values greater than $3$
are taken to show cells with especially poor agreement between
observed and expected counts. For my fake data, the residuals of greatest
interest are for lowest and highest-numbered categorical levels of satisfaction scores.

**Viewing satisfaction scores as actual numerical values.** The chi-squared test essentially ignores any numerical properties associated
with satisfaction scores (even order), treating numbers only as labels for nominal categorical levels.  Other kinds of tests, including
a 2-sample t test might be used if you want to treat satisfaction
scores as actual numbers.

In the data above, we could let $X$ (for full-time employees) have 'numerical' values
as follows: $191$ 1's, $319$ 2's, and so on. And similarly for $Y$ (for part-time employees). Whether to ascribe actual numerical meaning to Likert scores is controversial, but widely accepted as useful in the social sciences.

According to this scheme we have $X$ and $Y$ as follows:

```
x = rep(1:5, f);  y = rep(1:5, p)

par(mfrow=c(2,1))
 hist(x, br=(0:5)+.5, ylim=c(0,900), lab=T, 
      col="skyblue2", main="Full-Time")
 hist(y, br=(0:5)+.5, ylim=c(0,900), lab=T, 
      col="skyblue2", main="Part-Time")
par(mfrow=c(1,1))
```

[image]

Then a Welch 2-sample t test on the 'numerical' values in $X$ and $Y$ shows a highly significant difference in population means.

```
        Welch Two Sample t-test

data:  x and y
t = 23.437, df = 4063.8, p-value < 2.2e-16
alternative hypothesis: 
  true difference in means is not equal to 0
95 percent confidence interval:
 0.906221 1.071674
sample estimates:
mean of x mean of y 
 3.560914  2.571966
```

Comment: Thank you! How can I see if the job satisfaction of part-time workers is higher or lower than the job satisfaction of full-time workers?

Comment: In terms of the sample means $\bar X = 3.56$ and $\bar Y = 2.57$ shown in the output for the t test. (Subtract 1 and multiply by 25 to use the numerical scale 0, 25, 50 75, 100 of your Question.)  // In the two-way table, you might note that the median score for Full-Time is 4, while the median score for Part-Time is 2.

Comment: This is very helpful. Thank you. How can I find out if the difference in job satisfaction between part-time and full-time could be explained by gender (1 = male, 2 = female)?

Comment: Maybe use a two-factor ANOVA with factors Gender (levels M/F) and Job Type (F/P), with Likert observations hoped to be nearly normal. // Another possibility is to add a dimension to the table $2 \times 2 \times 5.$